# Postgres doc regaring INPUT function for CREATE TYPE does not seem to be correct

Tags: postgresql

I have created an input function for a datatype like the following:

```
mytimestamp(X)
```

The Postgres documentation states that in this case when the input function is called the type modifier will be passed as the 3rd parameter to the function. However, in my case the type modifier is always -1 which makes no sense. The following command:

```
select atttypid,atttypmod 
from pq_attribute 
where attname='mytimestamp';
```

shows that the type is created and the atttypmod value is what I expect. However, the input function still show the type modifier as -1. I've also tried to use the getBaseTypeAndTypmod function but it also returns a type modifier of -1. I am totally lost as to what to do next to resolve this problem.

Does this have anything to do with how I defined the type?

```
create type mytimestamp
( 
   INPUT = mytimestampin, 
   OUTPUT = mytimestampout,
   RECEIVE = mytimestamprecv,
   SEND = mytimestampsend,
   TYPEMOD_IN = mytimestamptypmodin,
--       TYPEMOD_OUT = mytimestamptypmodout,
   STORAGE = extended, 
   CATEGORY = 'd', 
   PREFERRED = true 
);
```

and the functions are defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytimestampin(cstring, oid, int4) RETURNS mytimestamp
            AS '$libdir/libmy_pgmod', 'mytimestampin'
            LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytimestampout(mytimestamp) RETURNS cstring
            AS '$libdir/libmy_pgmod', 'mytimestampout'
            LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytimestamprecv(internal, oid, int4) RETURNS mytimestamp
            AS '$libdir/libmy_pgmod', 'mytimestamprecv'
            LANGUAGE C STABLE STRICT;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytimestampsend(mytimestamp) RETURNS bytea
            AS '$libdir/libmy_pgmod', 'mytimestampsend'
            LANGUAGE C STABLE STRICT;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytimestamptypmodin(cstring[]) RETURNS int4
            AS '$libdir/libmy_pgmod', 'mytimestamptypmodin'
            LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
--CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytimestamptypmodout(int4) RETURNS cstring
--                AS '$libdir/libmy_pgmod', 'mytimestamptypmodout'
--                LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

I cannot place the full code here, however, here is the beginning:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(mytimestampin);
...
Datum mytimestampin( PG_FUNCTION_ARGS ) {
    const char     *pszTS      = PG_GETARG_CSTRING( 0 );
    uint32_t        atttypmod  = PG_GETARG_INT32( 2 );
    struct varlena *result     = NULL;
    PAPrSqBs_t      pTimestamp = NULL;
    PAPrSqCl_t      pCol       = NULL;
    int64_t         width      = 0;
    int             length     = 0;
    unsigned char  *pOut       = NULL;
    int32_t         precision  = -1;

    PAPrSqRcInit( );

    pTimestamp = PAPrSqBs_new( timestamp );
    pCol       = PAPrSqCl_new( timestamp );

    /**
     * Get the precision.
     */
    if ( (uint32_t)-1 == atttypmod ) {
            precision = PAPrSqCl_getPrecision( pCol, max );
    } else {
            precision = atttypmod;
    }
    ...

    /**
     * Destroy the column and timestamp types.
     */
    PAPrSqCl_delete( pCol );
    PAPrSqBs_delete( pTimestamp );

    PAPrSqRcClean( );

    PG_RETURN_POINTER( result );
}
```

There result of the query request is the following:

```
 attname |  atttypid   | atttypmod
---------+-------------+-----------
 TS      | mytimestamp |         6
 CHAR10  | mychar      |    656506
 VCHAR20 | myvarchar   |   1311866
 FB31    | integer     |        -1
 FB15    | smallint    |        -1
 DT      | mydate      |        -1
 TM      | mytime      |        -1
(7 rows)
```

Comment: What statement are you running to call the input function?

Comment: Hi Nick,

I created a table with the new custom type:

    create table t1(ts mytimestamp(8));

Then I try to insert into the table:

    insert into t1 values( '2016-09-06-15.24.35.123456' );

Inside of the mytimstampin function I get the timestamp string for the first parameter and the OID for the timestamp as the 2nd parameter. However, the 3rd parameter which should be the type modifier is -1 where I was expecting it to be 8.

Comment: Did you write a `TYPMOD_IN` function?

Comment: Yes, and I attach a debugger to the Postgres process and set a breakpoint in the function. That is how I know that the 3rd parameter being passed into the function is -1.

Comment: oops, sorry I was thinking of the wrong function but yes I do have a TYPMOD_IN function and I do the validation of the precision in that function (check for max, min, etc.). So I know the precision is ok in the TYPMOD_IN function. I just cannot see it in the INPUT function.

Comment: why would not you show the full code for type creation?..

Comment: Ok, I've updated the original text with the full definition of the create type and also added the function definitions as well.

Comment: Could you share the definition of `mytimestampin`? It should be similar to [`varcharin`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/varchar.c;hb=HEAD#l480). Also, can you share the result of `SELECT attname, atttypid::regtype::text, atttypmod FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute WHERE attrelid = 'mytable'::regclass
   AND attnum > 0 ORDER BY attnum` (replace `mytable` with your table name).

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I've added the extra information you requested above. As you can see from the query the typemod is set properly for the mytimestamp that I created. You will also notice that there is a mychar and myvarchar that also has type modifiers. They also exhibit the same issues as the mytimestamp as well.

Comment: I'd really appreciate some help with this. According to all the source I've looked and documentation it states that the 3rd parameter of the INPUT function should be the type modification value. However, that does not seem to be the case for me. It is always -1. If that is what should be expected then the parameter should be removed and the documentation updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Short answer

You need:

```
CREATE CAST(mytimestamp AS mytimestamp) WITH FUNCTION mytimestamp(mytimestamp, integer);
```

###### Explanation

You need a casting function from your type to... the same type, with a type modifier; this is necessary if you ever want to be able to apply/enforce the modifier a later point after the initial input.

You'd assume that `SELECT '2016-09-06-15.24.35.123456' ::mytimestamp(8)` will:

- call `mytimestampin` with *typemod 8*,

but instead you get:

- a call to `mytimestampin` with *typemod -1*, followed by
- a self-cast with *typemod 8*.

If no such self-cast was provided, it'll just shrug it off.

It's not really an issue related to the type definition (or `mytimestampin`), but an assumption that you'll have to provide at least a handful of casts for your type to be usable similar to the built-ins.

###### Reference

[PostgreSQL Documentation: Reference / SQL Commands / CREATE CAST — define a new cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createcast.html)

> Ordinarily a cast must have different source and target data types.
> However, it is allowed to declare a cast with identical source and
> target types if it has a cast implementation function with more than
> one argument. This is used to represent type-specific length coercion
> functions in the system catalogs. The named function is used to coerce
> a value of the type to the type modifier value given by its second
> argument.
>
> When a cast has different source and target types and a function that
> takes more than one argument, it supports converting from one type to
> another and applying a length coercion in a single step. When no such
> entry is available, coercion to a type that uses a type modifier
> involves two cast steps, one to convert between data types and a
> second to apply the modifier.